# Distributivity of 'must' over 'should' in elasticsearch queries

Tags: elasticsearch, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I felt puzzled by this behavior while querying my index.

Whether you interpret it in a boolean fashion or as sets (`OR` being a union and `AND` being an intersection), I take for granted that `X AND (Y OR Z) = (X AND Y) OR (X AND Z)`. In the following examples,

- `X` AnneeConstructionLogement < 1960
- `Y` ResultatGlobalAmiante = true
- `Z` TypeDiagnosticAmiante = "DAT"

### `X AND (Y OR Z)`

```json
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "AnneeConstructionLogement.keyword": {
              "lt": 1960
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
                {"term": {
                    "ResultatGlobalAmiante.keyword": true
                }},
                {"term": {
                    "TypeDiagnosticAmiante.keyword": "DAT"
                }}
              ]
          }
        }
      ]
 }
}
```

gives me **37 hits**

### `(X AND Y) OR (X AND Z)`

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "ResultatGlobalAmiante": true
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "AnneeConstructionLogement.keyword": {
                    "lt": 1960
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "TypeDiagnosticAmiante.keyword": "DAT"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "AnneeConstructionLogement.keyword": {
                    "lt": 1960
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

gives me **102 hits** which I find surprising, for **both are logically equivalent** (or, at least, I do not see any difference between those). Even more surprising, the [KQL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kuery-query.html) I started from `_index : ace-logement and AnneeConstructionLogement <= "1960" and ResultatGlobalAmiante: true or _index : ace-logement and AnneeConstructionLogement <= "1960" and TypeDiagnosticAmiante: DAT` gives me **134 hits**

Is this transposition of `must` and `should` on `AND` and `OR` relevant? Is this mismatch logic or implementation related?

Comment: As the numbers are not that big: can you check what documents are missing from each query and produce an hypothesis or minimal replication? I'm quite interested.

Comment: You're running some comparisons of `.keyword` (probably keyword subfields?) in *boolean match* and *range* queries which might return not exactly what you expect. Could you please double check all the data types and update the queries and results?

Comment: That was it!!!, thanks @ilvar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the use of `.keyword` (not sure why but interested to know). Thanks, @ilvar. I finally got the same number of hits

```json
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "AnneeConstructionLogement": {
              "lt": 1960
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
                {"term": {
                    "ResultatGlobalAmiante": true
                }},
                {"term": {
                    "TypeDiagnosticAmiante": "DAT"
                }}
              ]
          }
        }
      ]
 }
}
```

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "ResultatGlobalAmiante": true
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "AnneeConstructionLogement": {
                    "lt": 1960
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "TypeDiagnosticAmiante": "DAT"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "AnneeConstructionLogement": {
                    "lt": 1960
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You might keep keyword subfields (or update the mapping so that field itself is a `keyword`) for `TypeDiagnosticAmiante`